# Категории и темы

Tags: php, mysqli

Т.к я не силен в программировании, я смотрел курсы, видеоуроки и прочее в просторах интернета, но все равно опыта еще нет в решении проблем. В чем суть: Я написал небольшой скрипт на работу с БД и появилась задача, вывести категорию в которой будут темы. Т.е: Категория животные -Зайцы -Лиса -Волк Категория растения и т.д Думаю суть ясна, буду рад если вы мне поможете)

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "testdb";
$themes = "mybd";
$forum = "forum";
$connection = mysqli_connect("$host", "$dbuser", "$dbpassword", "$dbname");
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `$themes` ORDER BY `$themes`.`cat_id` ASC");
$fquery = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM `$forum` ORDER BY `$forum`.`cat_id` ASC");
$page = $_GET['id'];
while ($title = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fquery)) {
    echo $title['cat_title'];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "<hr>";
        echo "<h2 style='color: red;'>".$row['title']."</h2>";
        echo "<h4>".$row['text']."</h4>";
        echo "<hr>";
    }
}
?>
```

Продублировал с английского форума, т.к по ошибке спросил там.

Comment: Ключевое слово `JOIN`

Comment: Структуру таблиц можно увидеть?

Comment: Я уже как-то решил через INNER JOIN, но сейчас там другая проблема, но думаю 2 вопроса в одном тут запрещено, так что закрыто.